# Как сделать сортировку LinkedHashMap если value это объект со свойствами?

Tags: java, android

Например, как в случае ниже сделать сортировку по свойству volume. Ключ в моем случае - название товара.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, HolderGoods> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, HolderGoods>();

public class HolderGoods{
   public String id;
   public double price = 0;
   public double volume = 0;
}
```

Может использовать для этого не LinkedHashMap или можно и с ним все реализовать?
Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: А не проще будет название товара сделать полем класса `HolderGoods` и использовать простой `List` вместо мапы?

Comment: Изначально так и было, единственное, появилась необходимость фильтровать / удалять товары по названию, поэтому сделали LinkedHashMap, возможно это не самое хорошее решение, посоветуете лучше, буду только признателен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто, опишу общую схему решения:

1) Пишем компаратор для `HolderGoods`:

```
public class HolderGoods implements Comparable<HolderGoods> {
   public String id;
   public double price = 0;
   public double volume = 0;

   public int compareTo(HolderGoods holder) {
       return this.volume - holder.volume; //сортируем по возрастанию
   }
}
```

2) Из `LinkedHashMap` получаем `List`:

```
List<HolderGoods> holderList = new ArrayList<HolderGoods>(map.values());
```

3) Теперь у нас есть список в котором значения могут сравниваться, соответственно можно сортировать:

```
Collections.sort(holderList);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, теперь до меня окончательно дошло как быть с сортировкой!

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap` и любые ее реализации, к примеру - `LinkedHashMap` - используют хеш объектов для быстрого поиска. И хранят объекты внутри в определенном порядке. Вы не можете изменить порядок объектов в `HashMap`.

Если бы у вас был, к примеру, `List<HolderGoods>`, то тогда отсортировать было бы возможно:

```
List<HolderGoods> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(hg -> hg.volume));
```

Если же вы просто хотите пройти по значениям `Map` в порядке увеличения поля `volume`, то воспользуйтесь `stream api`:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, HolderGoods> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, HolderGoods>();

// проход по значениям
data.values().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(hg -> hg.volume)).forEach(hg -> {
    // логика тут
});

// проход по парам ключ-значение
data.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(entry -> entry.getValue().volume)).forEach(entry -> {
    // логика тут     
});
```

Однако прошу заметить. Метод с `stream`'ами не сортирует вашу мапу. Он лишь сортирует временную коллекцию, с которой вы работаете, никак не влияя на оригинальную `data`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Я уверен, что это работает и хорошо работает, но проверить на Java 8 сейчас не могу.

Comment: @SmartDragon ничего страшного, просто я большой поклонник лямбд, стримов и `chained` вызовов)